# Precise SVG mouseovers in CSS and HTML

Tags: dictionary, vector, svg, hover

I have a geometic shape that I would like to fill in, pictured

[image]

When the mouse is hovered over each area, I would like it to fill in, pictured here.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I add in the rest of the shapes, my code does not work, as my browser is giving each shape a bounding box that covers the rest of the shapes.  How can I make the mouseover shape of my svg precise and not a box?

Here is my `HTML` code:

```
<object data="images/logo/middle.svg" 
type="image/svg+xml" class="middlesvg hoversvg" > <!-- only the middle is shown for brevity -->
</object>
```

CSS

```
.hoversvg
{
    opacity: 0;
}

.hoversvg:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it straight in the SVG, no CSS required.

Draw each segment as its own polygon or path, and add a set attributeName tag into it:

```
<path … id="path1"><set attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1.0" begin="path1.mouseover" end="path1.mouseout"/></path>
<path … id="path1"><set attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1.0" begin="path2.mouseover" end="path2.mouseout"/></path>
```

etc.

This page has a bit more detail http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgint/ (scroll down to Events)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to implement the hovering within the middle.svg file. That way you can target the specific shape you want to change on hover.

Comment: I'm not particularly sure of what you mean; would you mind explaining?  Do I have to name the particular shape within my editor and then call on that shape name within CSS?

Comment: Show middle.svg and I can comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Give each `<path>` in the SVG an id, like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="first-path"/>
    <path id="second-path"/>
</svg>
```

Then you can select the individual paths in JS (e.g. `document.querySelector('#first-path')`) and do whatever you want with it.

To fill in the inside of the path, you could do something like this in your CSS:

```
#first-path {
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: fill; 
}

#first-path:hover {
    fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```